# How to store rmi connections in java?

Tags: java, rmi

I'm with a problem here.
I have a client `A` code that calls a `B` via RMI. After that I'm sending a queue request via JMS to the real implementation `C`. However, I don't know the "address" of `A`. Is there a way to store the connection data somehow so that I can return the data to `A` later?

Basically the thing is that `B` can have tons of requests and need to synchronize this to the requestor. How to do that?

Example:

A:

```
...
    rmiB.HelloWorld("Sys");
...
```

B:

```
String HelloWorld(String s) {
    ...
   sendToJMS(s);
    ...
   return????
}
```

C:

```
String HelloWorldOnJMS(String aff) {
    return "aff+2"
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the result of C's work to be returned as the result of A's remote method invocation? What is the current interface for returning data to A?

Comment: Yeah thats right, I'm getting A request on B and doing some work there and sending to a queue in JMS to C, and I want to get C result later and get for instance a value and send to A.
Basically I want to have a way to callback A outside the called rmi method.

Comment: There is no such thing as an RMI connection. Your question is really about callbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't modify `A`, then `B` needs to be responsible for blocking until `C` produces a result, and returning that result synchronous as the result of the RMI method.

So it seems the problem is more about how `C` can reply to `B` (or "Bs", since it sounds like you have a cluster of these) than how to respond to `A`.

Normally, synchronous calls like this are simulated via JMS by [creating a temporary queue,](http://java.sun.com/products/jms/javadoc-102a/javax/jms/QueueSession.html#createTemporaryQueue%28%29) and [specifying that as the reply address](http://java.sun.com/products/jms/javadoc-102a/javax/jms/Message.html#setJMSReplyTo(javax.jms.Destination)) on the message. So, `B` would create a temporary queue, then block on that queue until it received the result back from `C`, then return the content of the reply to `A`.

I might not understand your circumstances fully, but it seems like any other approach would require modifications to the `A`–`B` interface.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since A and B are already connected via a RMI locator, why not just have A register a service as well, and then let B call that service?

Comment: Well I can't modify A, since it's a client and I can't modify the interface.
Well I'm doing that because on my B code I'm doing balancing of servers. I'm treating a lot of things there for the "client" A.

Answer (score 0):

An RMI call forwarding to a JMSService? Sounds like [Apache Camel](http://activemq.apache.org/camel/) is exactly what you need; its a framework for doing just this sort of Enterprise integration.

The components [page](http://camel.apache.org/components.html) has examples of how to set up RMI and JMS (and myriad other) endpoints. You'll then write a route using its powerful DSL to forward messages from one endpoint to the other.

Comment: Definitely going to take a look at that :3